# QMAKE_INCDIR_QT and QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT in Qt5

Tags: qt4, qt5

Using Qt4 I could set a target platform having different qmake.conf files for the each one.

Now moving to Qt5 I noticed that QMAKE_INCDIR_QT and QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT that I use to specify the needed target binary version of Qt are vanished.

Which parameter or variable is to use instead for cross-compiling my application?

Comment: Do you have a qmake corresponding to a cross-compiled Qt?

Comment: Yes, I have. To be precise it was not cross-compiled. I was failed to cross-compile the Qt 5.5.1 for Windows under Linux because of shell-library dependencies; I compile it from source in another machine under the target system (my case the oldest Windows XP 32) and then copied it to the my work host machine.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5 and Qt 6, you can use `$$[QT_INSTALL_HEADERS]` and `$$[QT_INSTALL_LIBS]` instead.

**Hint:** Run `qmake -query` to see the values of all the defined `QT_*` properties on your system.